# ¿Cómo eliminar parte de un string?

Tags: php

Mi pregunta es cómo puedo eliminar una parte de un string hasta que consiga un carácter específico, por ejemplo:

Tengo esta url : `localhost/mipagina.com/condiciones.php?page=23`

Esa url quiero dejarla así: `localhost/mipagina.com/condiciones.php`

Quiero eliminar todos los caracteres que hayan cuando consiga el signo ?, incluyendo al signo ?.

Eso lo requiero para comparar un dato en una consulta.

Comment: Puedes resolverlo tmb con expresiones regulares, pero en si con un explode de php es posible dar rpta a tu inquietud. saludos.

Comment: Puedes utilizar también [parse_url($strin)](http://us.php.net/parse_url) de esta forma `$newurl = parse_url($url);` para luego solo acceder a `echo $newurl['path'];` y obtener el resultado correcto

Answer (score 11):

Buen día lo puedes hace de diferentes formas, a continuacion te planteo una utilizando la function nativa explode:

```
$url = "localhost/mipagina.com/condiciones.php?page=23";
$data = explode("?", $url);

$urlSinParams = $data[0];

echo "<br> - urlSinParams: ".$urlSinParams;
```

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.

Comment: Habia intentado con str_replace, pero asi con explode me parece mas corto el proceso! Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 7):

Puedes hacerlo con la siguientes funciones de PHP.

La primera sería [strpos](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php), la cual retorna la posición de la primera ocurrencia de la cadena.

Y la segunda sería [substr](http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php), la cual devuelve parte de una cadena dependiendo los parametros que se le inserten.

```
$variable = 'localhost/mipagina.com/condiciones.php?page=23';
$variable = substr($variable, 0, strpos($variable, "?"));
echo $variable; // localhost/mipagina.com/condiciones.php
```

Answer (score 5):

Por si te interesa, una solución mucho más sencilla sería usar la función [strstr](http://docs.php.net/function.strstr), aprovechándose del parámetro `before_needle`. De esta forma:

```
$url = 'localhost/mipagina.com/condiciones.php?page=23';
echo strstr($url, '?', true);
```

Nos devolvería la url que necesitas: `localhost/mipagina.com/condiciones.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso puede ser interesante el uso de **`strtok()`**.

[Según el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtok.php):

> `strtok()` divide un string (str) en strings más pequeños (tokens),
> con cada token delimitado por cualquier caracter de token. Es decir,
> si se tiene un string como "Este es un string de ejemplo", se puede
> tokenizar en sus palabras individuales utilizando el caracter de
> espacio como el token.
>
> Nótese que sólo la primera llamada a `strtok` utiliza el argumento
> string. Cada llamada subsecuente a strtok sólo necesita el token a
> utilizar, ya que realiza un seguimiento del lugar en que se encuentra
> en el string actual. Para volver a empezar, o para dividir una cadena
> nueva, simplemente se llama a `strtok` de nuevo con el argumento
> string para inicializarlo. Tener en cuenta que se pueden poner tokens
> múltiples como parámetro. El string será tokenizado cuando cualquiera
> de los caracteres en el argumento sea encontrado.

### Código

```
$baseURI=strtok('localhost/mipagina.com/condiciones.php?page=23','?');
var_dump($baseURI); # Test
```

**Salida:**

```
string(38) "localhost/mipagina.com/condiciones.php"
```